# Output through json_encode using PDO in php

Tags: php

I have being trying to output data from database using the below code but finding difficult displaying the fetched data on screen. Using PDO in php to trigger the selection. What should I do to resolve this issue?

```
<?php   

include ("core.php");
$output = array('data' => array());
$sql = "SELECT categories_id, categories_name, categories_active, categories_status FROM categories WHERE categories_status = ?";
$result = $connect->prepare($sql);
$result->execute([1]);

if($result->rowCount() > 0) { 

 // $row = $result->fetch_array();
 $activeCategories = ""; 

 while($row = $result->fetchAll()) {
    $categoriesId = $row[0];
    // active 
    if($row[2] == 1) {
        // activate member
        $activeCategories = "<label class='label label-success'>Available</label>";
    } else {
        // deactivate member
        $activeCategories = "<label class='label label-danger'>Not Available</label>";
    }

    $button = '<!-- Single button -->
    
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" id="editCategoriesModalBtn" data-target="#editCategoriesModal" onclick="editCategories('.$categoriesId.')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>

        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeCategoriesModal" id="removeCategoriesModalBtn" onclick="removeCategories('.$categoriesId.')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i> Remove</a></li>  

        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteCategoriesModal" id="deleteCategoriesModalBtn" onclick="deleteCategories('.$categoriesId.')"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li> 

      </ul> 
    </div>';

    $output['data'][] = array(      
        $row[1],        
        $activeCategories,
        $button         
        );  
 } // /while 

}// if num_rows

$connect = null;

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Please I below is the html code which accept the output. Please I'm just a beginner. Kindly help me.

````
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                            
                            <th>Categories Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th style="width:15%;">Options</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>```
````

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Currently you're populating the array $output and then encoding it in JSON before printing it.
What would you like to do exactly? Print the HTML code so it appears on the page?

Comment: Please i have the html code to be `<table class="table" id="manageCategoriesTable">
     <thead>
      <tr>       
       <th>Categories Name</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th style="width:15%;">Options</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>`

Comment: Where is the code where you try to process the JSON and put it into the page?

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchAll()` function will get you all the rows and columns, not just one. With that said, just get the variable `$row` outside of the `while` loop, call it differently (let's say, `$rows`), and then iterate over the loop using something like `foreach ($rows as $row)`. Also, now your $row will not take numerical indices, but rather indices with the names of what you selected in the SQL query, like `$row['categories_id']`. 
This should sort out iterating over the rows that you got. One more thing I'm not sure about is `$result->execute([1]);`, as that function takes parameters, and you're only giving it a 1-element array with the number 1, although I really can't tell because I don't have the rest of the code. 
 My guess is that you're trying to use JavaScript with AJAX, as you're printing the encoded $output variable, so you'll need to get the input at the very beginning using `php://input`, where you'll get all the parameters that are sent by AJAX, and, before encoding, set the content type to `application/json` using the function `header("Content-type: application/json");`